# gunicorn [/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket:6] Unknown section 'Service'. Ignoring

Tags: django, gunicorn

I'm setting up django on digitalocean, they have a setup rule that works this time though gunicorn won't work.

First step is setting up the gunicorn service using this command `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`

and the content

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=sammy
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/sammy/webapp/prestige
ExecStart=/home/sammy/webapp/envs/prestige/bin/gunicorn \
        --access-logfile - \
        --workers 3 \
        --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
        prestige.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and the socket file `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket`

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

note that this directory

```
/home/sammy/webapp/prestige
```

is the main folder directory of django with `manage.py` so basically if I cd into it I can run `python manage.py runserver` and it works.

this is the folder for the virtualenv

```
/home/sammy/webapp/envs/prestige
```

now when I run the start gunicorn command I get this

```
(prestige) sammy@prestige:~/webapp$ sudo systemctl start gunicorn.socket
Failed to start gunicorn.socket: Unit gunicorn.socket is not loaded properly: Invalid argument.
See system logs and 'systemctl status gunicorn.socket' for details.
```

if you check the status

```
(prestige) sammy@prestige:~/webapp$ sudo systemctl status gunicorn.socket
● gunicorn.socket - gunicorn daemon
Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
Active: inactive (dead)
May 17 07:25:18 prestige systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket:6] Unknown section 'Service'. Ignoring.
May 17 07:25:18 prestige systemd[1]: gunicorn.socket: Unit lacks Listen setting. Refusing.
May 17 07:33:32 prestige systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket:6] Unknown section 'Service'. Ignoring.
May 17 07:33:32 prestige systemd[1]: gunicorn.socket: Unit lacks Listen setting. Refusing.
May 17 07:34:09 prestige systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket:6] Unknown section 'Service'. Ignoring.
May 17 07:34:09 prestige systemd[1]: gunicorn.socket: Unit lacks Listen setting. Refusing.
May 17 07:53:41 prestige systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket:6] Unknown section 'Service'. Ignoring.
May 17 07:53:41 prestige systemd[1]: gunicorn.socket: Unit lacks Listen setting. Refusing.
May 17 07:56:59 prestige systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket:6] Unknown section 'Service'. Ignoring.
May 17 07:56:59 prestige systemd[1]: gunicorn.socket: Unit lacks Listen setting. Refusing.
```

No idea what's going on.

Comment: You need to show the gunicorn.socket file.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've added it

Answer (score 1):

Found out the hard way that if you put the wrong code for the service or socket for gunicorn it bugs out. After just deleting the droplet and starting again it went on smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

ENABLE gunicorn.socket after start it

```
sudo systemctl ENABLE gunicorn.socket
```

and make sure you link socket with gunicorn.service